# Cant prepare iOS app for submission

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Just submitted app to iTunes-connect and is available on TestFlight for internal users to test. I don't see a button to ultimately submit to App-Store for review. Rather than showing the newest build with a status "prepare for submission", I simply see current app store version with status "Ready for sale". How do I submit a new build. I am an admin. 
current app store version: 1.13.197, new build version: 1.14.200

Answer (score 2):

- go to your app and click (+ VERSION OR PLATFORM)(it is below your current version) and then choose iOS and add new version.
- after adding new version click on new version and just add newly uploaded build there and submit it for review.